# Parameters of Youtube-Channel with php ( Age, Description, Upload-Count... )

Tags: youtube-api

ich want to code a site with informations about some youtube-channels. I got the following parameters:

**Subscribers:**

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/*username*?alt=json");
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        echo '' . $data['entry']['yt$statistics']['subscriberCount'];
        ?>
```

**Chanel-Views:**

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/*username*?alt=json");
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        echo '' . $data['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
        ?>
```

**Total-Views:**

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/*username*?alt=json");
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        echo '' . $data['entry']['yt$statistics']['totalUploadViews'];
        ?>
```

But how could I get the **count of the uploaded Videos**. I only want to show the count how many videos were uploaded by this user.

And i want to show the **age, description, snippet, the date when he joined youtube**.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The number of public videos in a given YouTube channel can be obtained via the `openSearch$totalResults->$t` property of the uploads feed for that channel. Here's an example for `GoogleDevelopers`:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googledevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=json

```
"openSearch$totalResults": {
  "$t": 1458
}
```

Most of that other information you're looking for, regarding the channel creator's personal details, is no longer exposed on YouTube.com or via the API.